# SHA256 hash is not matching

Tags: hash, sha256

So I have a device and a server exchanging text file.

SHA256 hash is the way these two devices decide whether they are looking at the same file or the device needs to update to a new file the server sends.

The device and the server are looking at the same file but keep producing different hashes. I only have control over the server's hash calculation. Supposedly the device is also using SHA256 per original specs.

I've tried a few way to manipulate the original text file, such as explicit new lines, bytes versus string, etc, but could not yet match to the hash produced by the device.

I tried https://md5hashing.net/hash SHA256 decryption but it ran and ran and never returned a result.

Anything else I could try?

One example:

Server hash: 76f0fcbf047701b689a5cb2e1158eb3ac0c22b98a4dc9974223836da94bb6d6b

Device hash: 357174e720249ccfdc0522168dd57e45d77ef78a18f0cfdf76bf4f59e62a0055

Thanks!

Karl

Comment: You need to ensure that the input is byte-for-byte identical. So look at the actual bytes going into the server and the device. That's every single byte. I recommend looking at them in hex if possible; printing things out as ASCII or UTF-8 can hide small differences.

Comment: Another very common mistake is to accidentally hash an encoding (for example Base64). That's not the same thing as hashing the actual the actual data. For us to help you, you should should post the exact code you're using on server and device, along with the exact bytes you're passing to each.